# Database Query to ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I am not sure I am doing this right, with my limited knowledge of this programming language... or any for that matter.  Let's see if I can make this make sense so I can get some help.

I am running a query against my database to pull out all entries in the database

Part of DBAdapter.java:

```
//***RETRIEVES ALL THE FINALSCORES***//
public Cursor getAllFinalscores()
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_DATE,
            KEY_FINALSCORE,
            KEY_HOLESPLAYED},
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

I have then created a separate class which extends ListActivity (because I want all of the contents to be displayed in a listview.

PastGames.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class PastGames extends ListActivity {

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pastgames);



    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllFinalscores();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            String[] listData = new String [] {c.getString(1),
                    c.getString(2), c.getString(3)};
            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.pastgames, listData));
        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();


}
```

}

and then I am calling that from my Main activity (which just to note, does not extend ListActivity

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.past_games:
            Intent intentListGames = new Intent().setClass( this, PastGames.class );
            this.startActivityForResult( intentListGames, 0 );
            return true;
   }
        return true;
    }
```

---

So, if I understand this correctly, I am calling PastGames.java from my main activity (which then launches PastGames.java) and within PastGames.java - onCreate I am opening the db, running my query, closing and hopefully putting into listview

I get the following in LogCat when I run that option in emulator:

```
06-13 22:10:36.581: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.deckert/com.deckert.PastGames}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
06-13 22:10:36.581: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
06-13 22:10:36.581: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
06-13 22:10:36.581: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
```

Could someone please help me understand why this isnt working?

Thank you in advance and I apologize for the huge post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same layout in both your `ArrayAdapter` and your PastGames `Activity` root view.  I imagine that you do not want to use the `ListView`'s layout for your Activities layout.  I think this is what is causing the `ClassCastException`, because your `ListView`'s layout is probably defined to use just a simple `TextView`, and the Activity is blowing up saying that it cannot cast a `ListView` to a `TextView`.

Comment: So i removed the setContentView on create, and my XML file is a TextView in a linear layout.

I am now getting ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

what should I change for that?

Comment: GOT IT!  I needed to remove the linear layout from the xml and have it ONLY be textview!

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating correctly the adapter to be pass to the listView. If you have a look to the constructor of the adapter, is waiting for a TextView. And it doesnt make sense you have the same resource for the main layout and this textView. I think you need to create the Textview and pass it to the constructor ;)